# Unpacking nested JSON data from relational database in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, relational-database

this is my first question, so I hope I provide all the necessary details.

## My Problem

I'm fairly new to handling data with python, and I fight with the conversion of a specific type of dataframe. I'm accessing data from a relational database (Baserow) via an API. The output includes (among other data types) relation data of dictionaries within lists, like so:

```
[{'id': 1207327, 'value': 'foo'}, {'id': 1207330, 'value': 'bar'}]
```

In the respective columns, some cells are filled like this, others contain empty lists like so: `[]`.

So, the dataframe looks like this (only much bigger):

```
test_df = pd.DataFrame({'ID' : [1,2],
        'PROPERTY ONE': [
            [{'id': 1207327, 'value': 'foo'}, {'id': 1207330, 'value': 'bar'}],
            []
        ]})
```

Output:

```
   ID                                       PROPERTY ONE
0   1  [{'id': 1207327, 'value': 'foo'}, {'id': 12073...
1   2                                                 []
```

I am looking for a way to unpack this efficiently with pandas into fields containing plain lists or strings of `value` with some separator, e.g.

```
`[foo, bar]`
```

## Question

I have build a solution with two `for`-loops, but this looks inefficient and clumsy. Is there any way to achieve this in a vectorized way?

---

## What I have tried:

My `for`-loop-solution looks like this:

1. over all columns to find the respective columns
2. within each column over individual rows/cells, unpacking the lists to  individual data to dataframes and converting the respective columns to lists.

The second loop looks like this:

```
new_column = []
    for array in column:
        tmp_dfr = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(array)
        length = tmp_dfr.empty
        if not tmp_dfr.empty:
            values = tmp_dfr['value'].tolist()
        else:
            values = []
        new_column.append(values)
    new_column = pd.Series(new_column)
```

As described above, I am not happy with the way this is achieved, as it is faster and more efficient to work in a vectorized way, as I understand.

I have also looked into several seemingly related questions on this site (e.g. [here]([pandas DataFrame: normalize one JSON column and merge with other columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49671693/pandas-dataframe-normalize-one-json-column-and-merge-with-other-columns) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28655405/how-to-deal-with-pandas-column-that-has-a-list-of-dicts-in-every-cell)). But as I am at the moment just fumbling my way into pandas, I am not able to transfer the solutions to my problem. Instead, I am running into all kinds of exceptions, maybe because some of the cells contain empty lists...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating many extra dataframes is certainly inefficient because it creates extra overhead. You can just use a list comprehension instead (the `simplify` function). That way there's also no need to special-case the empty list. I would use [`pandas.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) for converting the elements. Using `.map` instead of some form of iteration makes clear that the operation doesn't depend on results from higher up in the table.

```py
def simplify(json_list):
    return [json_object["value"] for json_object in json_list]

test_df['NEW COLUMN'] = test_df['PROPERTY ONE'].map(simplify)
```

The output is:

```
   ID                                       PROPERTY ONE  NEW COLUMN
0   1  [{'id': 1207327, 'value': 'foo'}, {'id': 12073...  [foo, bar]
1   2                                                 []          []
```

If you're a fan of brevity, you can use a lambda function instead of the named function:

```py
test_df['NEW COLUMN'] = test_df['PROPERTY ONE'].map(
    lambda json_list: [json_object["value"] for json_object in json_list]
)
```

Comment: Thank you, that does the trick. I also like the mapping which helps me to keep the code explicit and understandable for a newby like me. That's also the reason I'd choose the separate function over brevity. – Also, with regard to the answer by @mozway below, is there a best practice of lists over json objects in this case?

Comment: I don't understand your question. @mozway's answer only differs by using a second list comprehension instead of the map & function and by shorter variable names. The basic logic is equivalent. I only used names referring to the respective JSON values because you mentioned that in your title.

Comment: My fault, @Joooeey. I'm still a newbie and misunderstood your names (`json_list` etc.) for expressions. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot vectorize this since this is an object column with python objects, you can however greatly simplify the code to use a nested list comprehension, which should be much faster:

```
test_df['new_col'] = [[d['value'] for d in l]
                      for l in test_df['PROPERTY ONE']]
```

Output:

```
   ID                                       PROPERTY ONE     new_col
0   1  [{'id': 1207327, 'value': 'foo'}, {'id': 12073...  [foo, bar]
1   2                                                 []          []
```

Comment: Thank you! That works fine. I combine it with the mapping proposed by @Joooeey above.

Comment: @Sereios you're welcome, however `map` should be less efficient

Comment: Thank you for the info, @mozway. I was not aware of that. At the moment I like the style that comes with `map` and it doesn't seem problematic. However, I will keep your solution in mind in case I run into issues with large datasets!